# Hyphen breaks on new line instead of taking the whitespace on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a small problem on mobile devices with CSS3 and HTML5 and Responsive design using Bootstrap 3.

On a desktop or laptop when I resize my window to smaller then the text lines are wrapped to new lines using the whitespaces.

When I use my Samsung Galaxy S6 it uses the `-` hyphen to wrap instead of the whitespace.

How can I disable this wrapping on hyphen `-` in CSS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following css :

```
.nowrap {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="big">Autoparts Prosec is de grossier in 
   <strong class="nowrap">auto-onderdelen</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Still the same... It takes the hyphen to wrap instead of the whitespace.

Comment: can u give me jsfiddle for reference ?

Comment: I just had the same solution! Thanks